# Vue Router’s paths to assets break on reload

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-router

I'm working with Webpack 4.43, Vue 2.6.11 & Vue Router 3.1.6

Webpack generates a `dist` folder with a `bundle.js` and an `index.html`.

If I navigate to nested pages through the app links everything works fine, but if I try to reload a nested page, the `index.html` can't load `bundle.js` because it tries to find it at the nested page level. For example if I go to `localhost:8080/fr/contact` it will try to load `localhost:8080/fr/bundle.js`

I've seen many other related topic but no one ever gives a real answer. Does anyone have a solution?

EDIT: Don't know if it helps, but I just realized that the images don't load in nested pages even when I reach them through the `router-links`. Same problem: it looks for `localhost:8080/fr/my-image.png` instead of `localhost:8080/my-image.png`

Comment: Check that your `publicPath` has the right value for your use case (https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath)

Comment: I already tried creating a `vue.config.js` file at the root of my project, but whatever I put in `publicPath` doesn’t seem to change anything. This seems to be a Vue Cli config, which I do not use.

Comment: If you do not use `publicPath` then by default it is `/` - which means that you should deploy your application in the root folder of your domain name. Otherwise it will not work correctly - e.g. if you deploy in `/fr` folder instead.

Comment: It's not even deployed yet, it's running with Webpack dev-server, at localhost:8080... I wouldn't even know what to put in publicPath instead of "/".

Comment: If you are running the `webpack-dev-server` then `/dist` is out of the question since it (the `dev` server) serves everything from RAM. The `/dist` folder is used only for deployment - not for development.

Comment: @IVOGELOV You're right, it actually doesn't use the dist folder. Which doesn't solve my problem and makes it even more confusing. I tried a few things:

Comment: - When I use webpack dev-server and reload a nested page, the link to ´bundle.js´ is broken, as I described
- When I build into ´dist´, open the generated ´index.html´ file with WebStorm, and reload a nested page, it gives me a 404 error (even with an ´.htaccess´ in the same folder to redirect the requests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it by setting `publicPath: '/'` in my Webpack config (not the Vue config). Here's how it looks:

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    ...
}
```